# How to call a parameter value outside the function under a class?

Tags: python, function, class, parameters

Here is one example code below. I would like to call a parameter value, which is created inside the function under a class, from outside any function, let's say from the python shell...

I have first tried calling it with the instance of the class created by me as:

`tc.process_time_in_seconds`

in the python shell console and after running the code and the line `tc.process_time_in_seconds` in the shell it returns:

`NameError: name 'tc' is not defined`

as a result...therefore I need to find a way to do it correcly. I guess predefining the `tc` outside any class or function. I am not sure how I would do it correctly.. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import time
import datetime

class TimeCounter:

    def startTime(self):

        self.start_time_of_the_script = time.time()


    def endTime(self):

        self.end_time_of_the_script = time.time()
        self.process_time_in_seconds = self.end_time_of_the_script - self.start_time_of_the_script
        print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=self.process_time_in_seconds))


def main():

    tc = TimeCounter()
    tc.startTime()
    tc.endTime()

main()
```

Comment: `tc` is defined _within_ your `main` function. So outside the function, the name is not known. If you want to use it outside of it, you will have to declare it outside of it (or return it, or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't access `tc` from outside of `main` is that it's a local variable. Local variables only exist inside the function that creates them; once that function returns, the variables are gone forever.

> I guess predefining the tc outside any class or function. I am not sure how I would do it correctly..

What you're asking for is how to change `tc` from a local variable to a global variable.

---

In general, this is a really bad idea. If you want a value to stick around after a function is done with it, a better solution is to `return` the value:

```
def main():    
    tc = TimeCounter()
    tc.startTime()
    tc.endTime()
    return tc
```

… and then have the caller store it:

```
t = main()
```

Now, you have a variable named `t` at the same scope as that `main()` call, with the same value as the local `tc`. So, in your interactive session, you can just do this:

```
t.process_time_in_seconds
```

I gave `t` a different name from `tc` just to make it obvious that the two variables are unrelated names for the same value. If you want to use the same name for both, that's fine too.

---

But sometimes—especially when doing stuff at the interactively interpret—globals really are simpler. Whenever you find yourself reaching for a global variable, you should stop and ask whether there's a better way to do it. But when there isn't, here's how you do it: add a `global` statement at the start of the function.

```
def main():
    global tc
    tc = TimeCounter()
    tc.startTime()
    tc.endTime()
```

Now, instead of creating a local variable named `tc`, the `main` function is creating or modifying a global variable named `tc`. So, after you've called `main()`, you can access that global variable:

```
tc.process_time_in_seconds
```

Depending on what kind of interactive stuff you're planning to do, this may be just as good as the `return` version and a bit simpler, or it may cause unnecessary problems or restrictions, like not being able to call `main()` twice and get back two different values. If you don't know, always err on the side of not using globals. But when you do know you want one, go for it.

Comment: It seems like more or less I have to define things globally. If I am not able to define more than one **return** functions. Or can I?

Comment: @questioneer1 I have no idea what "if I am not able to define more than one return functions" means. You can return multiple values in a single statement, like `return a, b, c`, and you can unpack multiple values into separate variables, like `x, y, z = spam(q)`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Ow! To be able to write **return a, b, c** is completely new to me and while unpacking to be able to give different variable names like x, y, z is also new to me. It should be more aesthetic in the logic of progragramming.

Answer (score 0):

As `@poke` already pointed out, you *cannot* reference that item any more.  You created `tc` as a local variable within the `main` function.  You called a couple of instance methods that set attributes, and then you left the scope of `tc` -- that being `main`.  You failed to do anything to make the object available outside `main`.  The simplest way would be to return the object, like so:

```
def main():

    tc = TimeCounter()
    tc.startTime()
    tc.endTime()
    return tc

outer = main()
print(outer.process_time_in_seconds)   # proof of concept ... not within the interpreter.
```

Output:

```
0:00:00.000003
2.6226043701171875e-06
```

Comment: Yes it worked also. However, I wont be able to use **outer** object inside my main function. Assuming I would have other classes working under the main, step by step running.. Therefore using **global** might seem to be the only option for me..